# When should you raise a set to a power?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

The definition of a symmetric relation is often given as:

$\forall x,y \in X,\ xRy \Rightarrow yRx$.

is there any reason why it isn't:

$\forall (x,y) \in X^2,\ xRy \Rightarrow yRx$?

to my mind, it makes sense to think about each vertex on a 2D grid with dimensions $|X| \times |X|$ as having a truth value for this statement, and in that instance you would be taking $x$ and $y$ from two different, but identical sets..

I use this definition just as an example, but my question is more generally about how to correctly use notation when selecting more than one element from a set in this way. Sometimes I do see things like $\ldots \in X^4$ written, but I am not sure what the pattern is behind it and when it should be used.

Is this just a convention that some people use, and others don't? or should it only be used when ordered tuples are explicitly needed?

Comment: Convention. Some goes for readability and write $a,b,c\in X$. Some wants to seem more rigorous and write $(a,b,c)\in X^3$ for the same.

Comment: Ah great, thank you, I thought it might be convention, but i didn't know for sure.

Comment: That means *ellipsis* is accepted in proofs.

Comment: Convention to some extent, but writing $\forall (x,y)$ is also not well-formed logical syntax. Quantifiers bind *variables* and $(x,y)$ is not a variable, it's a term with two free variables. Further, the particular formula in question goes on to use the free variables of that term separately anyway, so talking about elements of $X^2$ doesn't do any work. That said, I'd guess most readers would understand what you're saying if you used the latter form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: writing $x,y\in X$ is just a shorthand for $x\in X$ and $y\in X$, or equivalently $(x,y)\in X^2$.

If you see written $a,b\in X^2$ that just means $a\in X^2$ and $b\in X^2$; in other words, $a=(x,y)$ and $b=(z,w)$ for some $x,y,z,w\in X$ (there I just used the shorthand ;) ).

Comment: ah, great explanation, that is very clear.. thank you